# Bind where clause to a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input:

When Process ID = 610

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | 2 |
| 60 | 16 |
| // | 2 |
| 80 | 128 |

I have two separate queries that fetch two values from the same table so I am trying to merge them together instaed of calling the table twice.

```
select [serialno],[storedatetime], [value1], [value2], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [serialno] ORDER BY [storedatetime] desc) AS RowNumber 
    from [database] 
    where [processid] = 610 and [stepid] = 50
```

When this is run the where clause  applies to [value1] and nothing is set for [value2]
I am trying to make a different where clause to apply to [value2] where the [stepid] is a different number like:

```
  where [processid] = 610 and [stepid] = 80
```

This is quite new to me and haven't managed to find a way yet.
Any help is appreciated.

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: You tag the question with [mysql] tag but use SQL Server (MS SQL) syntax.. check your DBMS carefully !

Comment: Can you not do: ... and [stepId] = 50 or [stepId] = 80?

Comment: That doesn't match it to either then

Comment: @Byron: This would have to be `and ([stepId] = 50 or [stepId] = 80)`, because without parentheses you'll get undesired results. And still, this would produce two rows for a processid, where it shall be one.

Comment: On a side note: a database and a table are different things. A database consists (mainly) of tables.

Comment: I don't know what a layered table is. What columns does the table have? Does it have a column called value1 (which is filled for stepid 50 and empty for stepid 80) and a column called value2 (filled vice versa)? Or is there really only one column called value and you want the value for stepid 50 to appear as value1 and the value for stepid 80 as value2 in your result?

Comment: Within the table there is the column [processid] where for each item in that column there is a seperate list which is [stepid] that contains number for each step as shown in the input. Value1 and value 2 are just names I put to store [stepid] = 50 and [stepid] = 80 from [processid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need in this:

```sql
SELECT [serialno],
       [storedatetime], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [stepid]= 50 THEN {some_column_name} END) [value1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [stepid]= 80 THEN {some_column_name} END) [value2],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [serialno] ORDER BY [storedatetime] desc) AS RowNumber 
FROM [database] 
WHERE [processid] = 610 and [stepid] IN (50, 80)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Essentially like this but it gives: 
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: @JoshM If so then move everything except `RowNumber` to CTE and add enumeration in outer query.

Comment: No. As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't allow positional group by. So, change this to `[GROUP BY serialno], storedatetime]`.

Comment: Still only likes the one column and then nothing for value2, I have added an output to my question which is what I get with most attempts

Comment: @JoshM Provide a sample. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Added, it's a layered table so selected the processid gives me the range of stepid and I am trying to pull two separate ones

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer the aggregation shown in Akina's answer, you may find a join more straight-forward. Select the value1 rows, select the value2 rows, join the two.

```
select
  v1.serialno, v1.storedatetime, v1.value1, v2.value2,
  row_number() over (partition by v1.serialno order by v1.storedatetime desc) as rownumber 
from
(
  select serialno, storedatetime, value1
  from database
  where processid = 610 and stepid = 50
) v1
join
(
  select serialno, storedatetime, value2
  from database
  where processid = 610 and stepid = 80
) v2 on v2.serialno = v1.serialno and v2.storedatetime = v1.storedatetime;
```

Comment: This is what I have previously, I am trying to condense it as the two values are from the same table

Comment: So, you had written a query like this this and it worked, and now you are merely looking for a smaller query that does the same? In your request it sounds like you were not able to find a query that shows both values in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Slight tweak using both answers and this gets the right results

```
SELECT [serialno],[storedatetime],  
    MAX(CASE WHEN [stepid]= 50 THEN [value1] END) [value1], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN [stepid]= 80 THEN [value1] END) [value2], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [serialno] ORDER BY [storedatetime] DESC) AS RowNumber 
FROM [spi_mfg].[dbo].[processdata] 
WHERE [processid] = 610 AND [stepid] IN (50, 80) 
GROUP BY [serialno], [storedatetime]
```